# Automatically Generate Attribute Table in Qgis

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, attribute-joins

I am working with historical parcel data in Qgis and have the following fields in my attribute table, `(name, grantee date, grantor date, parcel ID, acreage, previous owner)`. Unfortunately, I have around 10-15 already created parcels that does not have these fields in the table. Is there an easy way to have those fields automatically generated in those attribute tables or will I have to manually enter them?

Comment: In order to automatically add attribute data, you have to pull that data from somewhere. QGIS can't create information out of thin air. Please provide information about what format you have the field data in.

Comment: How big is this project - how much data will you be creating / maintaining, and what is the duration of the project? Could be a perfect use for a PostGIS database...

Answer (score 1):

if the values are same, you can enter them directly through field calculator.

Comment: Unfortunately they are not. The first parcels attribute may be look like this: John Doe, 1897, 1909, 0944567, 40, Jane Doe. The next parcel may have the following entry: Steve Smith, 1888, 1921, 80, Adam Smith.

Comment: If you have a table you can join the tables